# Url Generation Error (Missing Required Keys :id) on devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a rails 4 application, I have been working on it for quite a while and Register and Login worked until I added a few things and users cannot log in anymore and I can't figure out what it is I did and now I cannot start a session.
This is the exact error;

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in SessionsController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"controllers"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Before you point me to other questions like this, I have gone through every single on of them and none of them seem to be related to devise's session controller.
Here is my full stack trace;

```
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:721:in `generate'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:752:in `generate'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:799:in `url_for'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:223:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
devise (4.4.3) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:48:in `auth_options'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.10) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Now I realize that the error is pointing me to my session controller, line 7, I also have no idea why. But here is my session controller's contents in case;

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
      super
    end

    def create
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      if !session[:return_to].blank?
        redirect_to session[:return_to]
        session[:return_to] = nil
      else
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      end
    end
  end
```

Please note that I overrode (if there's any such word) my sessions controller in na attempt to try to fix the error, but I still come up with the same thing.
Please let me know if you need any more of my code to be able to point me in the right direction.

I am also overriding after_sign_in_path_for in application_controller as someone suggested, but it is still the same error.
This is it

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(users)
    flash[:notice] = nil
    dashboard_path
  end
```

Here is my `routes.rb` file as requested for.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :confirmeds
  resources :confirmings
  resources :donates
  resources :respondings
  resources :confirmings
  resources :controllers
  resources :referrals




  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations"}



  resources :welcome

  get '/dashboard' => 'welcome#dashboard'
  post '/dashboard' => 'welcome#dashboard'

  get '/registered' => 'welcome#registered'
  post '/registered' => 'welcome#registered'

  get '/error' => 'welcome#error'
  post '/error' => 'welcome#error'

  get '/error2' => 'welcome#error2'
  post '/error2' => 'welcome#error2'

  get '/level' => 'welcome#level'
  post '/level' => 'welcome#level'

  get '/referralid' => 'welcome#referralid'
  post '/referralid' => 'welcome#referralid'

  get '/report' => 'welcome#report'
  post '/report' => 'welcome#report'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I did, In a custom registrations_controller and also in applications_controller because I wasnt sure which one was actually controlling it.

Comment: Alright, I will do that and see if it works

Comment: I have removed it, still the same error.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: change `dashboard_path` to `dashboards_path` ?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason why? the path to `/dashboard` is `dashboard_path` in my routes

Comment: If dashboard_path is a valid path, then it suggests you're not hitting this method. Try putting a binding.pry just before the dashboard_path and see if it gets hit or not

Comment: I think after_sign_in_path would be executed after a successful sign in or sesssion creation. Sign in isnt sucessful, so it makes sense that it wont hit dashboard_path just yet

Comment: It's trying to redirect to a route like `/controllers/:id`. `/controllers/...` doesn't sound like a valid destination. Any chance you have bad data in the `session[:return_to]`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? does this also mean the session won't be created at all?

Comment: what does your routes.rb look like?

Comment: Please share your `routes.rb`. Like @AaronBreckenridge mentioned after login, it's trying to redirect to a route with `:id`.

Comment: I just updated the question with my `routes.rb`

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?